# how can i receive a specific client with recvfrom function

Tags: sockets, client, udp, client-server

In a server by using udp socket, how can i receive data from a specific client? i know that how to use recvfrom and sender address is also returned. but the problem is that recvfrom function receives data from any client. but i want for example, recvfrom receive data only for client2. (with address cliAddr2); How can i do this? (i am using c languange on linux)

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`connect()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) similar to TCP sockets to limit packets to one source.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can not prevent recvfrom() from receiving data from any client,
the only way is to drop the data in your program yourself or use netfilter/iptables for example.